# How do you move a directory in perforce using the command line?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to move a directory into another directory in perforce. This is by the command line. The only command I can find to move items is the move command, which only moves individual files. Is their a way to just move all of the files in one directory to another? My directory structure has many levels and it would be tedious to have to issue the command to move each one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `p4 move` to move whole tree. But before that, all files in the moved directory have to be opened for edit or add.

For example:

```
p4 edit //xyz/...
p4 move //xyz/... //abc/...
```

will move all *already tracked* files in `//xyz` and its subdirectories.

(cfr the [documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/move.html) :)

Comment: Note that the files have to be open for add/edit first.

Comment: If you get a *file(s) not opened on this client* error you have to checkout all the files you want to move first.